# How can I get rid of keyword QuerySet in return value from model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with custom properties. In my admin I display the return value from the model. The return values from all properties start with the following words in each record.

```
<QuerySet [
```

I am trying to get rid of the `<QuerySet [` from showing up in every record as shown in the image?
When I display the return value from get_followers, get_following, get_friends, all the return values contain `<QuerySet [`

Any idea how I can do this?

[image]

```
class Application(TimeStampModel):
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='CI Name', max_length=100, unique=True)
relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',
                                       symmetrical=False,
                                       related_name='related_to')

def get_following(self):

    return self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)


def get_followers(self):
    return u'%s' % self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

def get_friends(self):

    return self.relationships.filter(
        to_apps__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING,
        to_apps__from_application=self,
        from_apps__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING,
        from_apps__to_application=self)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.name)

RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING = 1
RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED = 2
RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = (
    (RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 'Following'),
    # Following: denotes the relationship from the user, i.e. following
    (RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED, 'Blocked'),
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `u'%s' % self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)` you are using the `repr()` of the queryset, which includes the `<QuerySet [` which you do not want.

An alternative to get a list of strings for the items in the queryset, and join these together:

```
def get_followers(self):
    return ", ".join(str(x) for x in self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)))
```

If you actually use the queryset elsewhere in your code, then create a separate methods (e.g. `get_friends_display`), and use the new method in your model admin's `list_display`.

```
def get_friends_display(self):
    return ", ".join(str(x) for x in self.get_friends())
```

Comment: Works perfect. Now I just need to figure out how to show the count of friends in front of each app. Like in admin panel in front of each app, display the count of friends (i.e. appname(5))